# Failed to Enable AutoFill Service by using Intent in Android O

Tags: android, android-service, android-autofill-manager

I used this code for enabling the Enable AutoFill Service.

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE);
        startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

I got the next exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.android.autofillframework, PID: 7683
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.autofillframework/com.example.android.autofillframework.app.StandardSignInActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE }
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1936)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi16.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityApi16.java:54)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:65)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:711)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
at com.example.android.autofillframework.app.StandardSignInActivity.onCreate(StandardSignInActivity.java:53)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the package name in the intent. From the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE):

*Input: Intent's data URI set with an application name, using the "package" schema (like "package:com.my.app").*

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the package name in the intent. pass your app package name in intent.setData().
like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_SET_AUTOFILL_SERVICE);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:<YOUR_APP_PACKAGE_NAME>"));
startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 3):

On Huawei devices, it seems like this even happens if you check correctly for  hasEnabledAutofillServices() and isAutofillSupported() and if you include the package.

Comment: I'm now catching ActivityNotFoundException and display a message that the user should enable autofill in the settings.

Comment: You can use this instead of catching the exception.

`getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0).size() > 0`